# React website buttons and inputs don't work on smartphone

Tags: reactjs, button, input, react-router, smartphone

It is a simple website:
https://www.tradecalc.eu
The website works properly in a desktop browser. But it doesn't work properly on smartphones (only works in "computer mode"). Not working all "buttons" and "inputs". There are no errors in the browser console. At least I didn't notice any of these. The website is built with:

- React (Hooks)
- React Router (HashRouter)
- Bootstrap:
  `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` in "index.js" file.
  The most important codes of "buttons" and "inputs":

```
<input
    id="price"
    name="price"
    type="number"
    step="0.01"
    min="0.1"
    className="form-control"
    autoFocus
    required
    onChange={e => setPrice(e.target.value)} />
```

```
<input
    id="percent"
    name="percent"
    type="number"
    min="0"
    className="form-control"
    required
    onChange={e => setPercent(e.target.value)} />
```

```
<select
    name="currency"
    id="currency"
    className="form-control"
    onChange={e => setCurrency(e.target.value)}>
    {currencyList.map(({ label, value }) => (
       <option key={value} value={value}>
         {label}
       </option>
    ))}
</select>
```

The form "buttons":

```
<button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mr-2">Count</button>
<button type="reset" className="btn btn-outline-secondary" onClick={() => setCount(0)}>Reset</button>
```

The rest of the "buttons":

```
<Link type="button" className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" to="/">
   Back to Trade Calc
</Link>

<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
   <img src={linkedin} alt="LinkedIn" />
</a>

<Link style={{ color: "red" }} to="/donation">
   Make a Donation
</Link>

<Link style={{ color: "black" }} to="/privacy">
   Privacy & Cookies Policy
</Link>
```

If you need more code, please let me know.

Comment: Can you try removing the "privacy / cookie policy" notice from your app? I am sure that notice "div" is the problem. When we click "OK" of this notice, the notice seems to disappear but stays in the DOM over the input fields and buttons. So, "removing that notice" is the first step towards solving your problem.

Comment: Yes. This is it. I fixed it. I moved "CookieNotice" to a neutral place. Now everything works properly on the smartphone. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with JS but CSS/Markup. Your Cookie banner is overlapping the form. If you try `Tab`(from keyboard) to navigate to the next tab you see it will work for you, but since the container `react-cookienotice-*` is lying over the top of your form so you won't be able to enter values in the `input` fields.

[image: Cookie Banner]

Comment: Yes. This is it. I fixed it. I moved "CookieNotice" to a neutral place. Now everything works properly on the smartphone. Thank you very much for help.